# Showing a warning message when before_create fails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In one of my models, I have a before_create attribute that sets a particular value, fetched from a web API. However, this before_create returns false, killing the model creation, if no results are found when using the API.

This works fine, but I would like to also show a warning message, so that the users know their input was not accepted. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Please post your `before_create` and other relevant code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `before_create` isn't the right place to be reporting errors. Your `before_create` should try to set the value and then a validator should check if it is there, if the validator doesn't find the value then you'll get your error message and such. So, if your attribute is called `pancakes`, then you'd have something like this:

```
before_validation :stuff_web_api_value_into_pancakes, :if => :new_record?
validates_presence_of :pancakes
```

You could, of course, use a different validator than `validates_presence_of`, that's just there for illustrative purposes. And you'll want a [`before_validation` hook](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#creating-an-object) to get things to happen in the right order, the `:if => :new_record?` will only run the hook when you're creating a new model.

Comment: Where can I find this API for pancakes?!

Comment: I believe validations run before `before_create`.

Comment: @madh: I think you believe correctly, the [guide lists the callbacks in order](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#creating-an-object). Thanks for the heads-up, I've fixed things.